# Prove $2^n > a\cdot n^2$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. ($a$ is a constant in $\mathbb{R^+}$)

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, logarithms, asymptotics

Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R^+}$. I need to prove $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, 2^n > a\cdot n^2$.

Both L'Hôpital's rule and Lambert's W function are **NOT** allowed to use other than inequality or taking logarithm. I understand there is a classical induction proof for $2^n > n^2$, but this one seems to be tricky because of the constant $a$.

I have tried several approaches, but I cannot seem to figure out a $n$ (which 
 most likely involves $max()$, $\lceil\rceil$). One approach I tried was to take $n = \lceil n_0 + log_2a\rceil$, where $n_0 \in \mathbb{R^+}$. But I cannot seem to prove that 
\begin{equation}
2^{n - log_2a} > n^2
\end{equation}

Am I on the right track or totally off? Can someone show please help with this proof? It has been bugging me for a while. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The inequality obviously holds if $a\leq 0$. I am sure you forgot to say $a>0$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{n}=(1+1)^{n}$. By Binomial Theorem we see that $2^{n} >1+n+\frac {n(n-1)} 2$. I will leave it to you to find out how large $n$ should be for $1+n+\frac {n(n-1)} 2 >an^{2} $.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thank you so much for the timely response! Can I just follow through your answer here? Since I wanted to find a solid $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it seems I can use the quadratic formula to find out the solution to $n$ in inequality $(1-2a)\cdot n^2 + n + 2 > 0$ (derived from your answer). Then I got, $n_0 = \frac{\sqrt{1-8(1-2a)} - 1}{2(1-2a)}$, for $a > \frac{7}{16}$. Then let $n = \lceil n_0 \rceil$. This seems to be the answer I have been looking for. Am I right? Is there any case I might be missing?

Comment: @PeterForeman Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @auchen_h Are you trying to find the best constant $a$? The question asks you to find just one $a$ for which the inequality holds and you are making things too complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made the context too confusing. I am trying to find a $n\in \mathbb{N}, 2^n > a\cdot n^2$, where $a$ is just a constant in $\mathbb{R^+}$. That's why I was solving the quadratic equation. Your suggestion on expanding $2^n$ using Binomial Theorem was extremely helpful. I am just wondering if my thoughts following were correct to find such $n$. Namely, solve the quadratic equation $(1-2a)n^2 + n + 2 > 0$. Then  $n = \lceil n_0 \rceil$, where $n_0 = \frac{\sqrt{1-8(1-2a)} - 1}{2(1-2a)}$, $\frac{7}{16} < a < \frac{1}{2}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @auchen_h Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{2^x}{x^2}$. It is obvious that it is an increasing function and tends to infinity for $x\ge1$. Therefore, given a constant $a$, we must find a $N$ that for any positive integer $n\ge N$, $\dfrac{2^n}{n^2}> a$, which means $2^n>a\times n^2$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reponse!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {2^x\over x^2}=\infty$$therefore ${2^x\over x^2}$ can be arbitrarily greater than any real number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually looking for some proof that only involves number theory. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

How about proving like this?

Since $\lceil a \rceil n^2 \ge an^2$, we only have to prove that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}(2^n > mn^2)$ when $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let us define the forward difference $\Delta f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ of a function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ as this:
$$\Delta f(n) := f(n + 1) - f(n)$$
Simple observation shows that for a polynomial function $P$, the forward difference of it is also a polynomial function of degree one lesser than $P$. By induction, we can see that if we apply forward difference sufficiently many times, it will eventually become a constant function.

And now we prove a proposition to utilize this.

> **Proposition**: For two functions $f, g\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$, if there
>   exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\Delta f(n) > \Delta g(n)$ for
>   all natural number $n \ge M$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such
>   that $f(n) > g(n)$ for all natural number $n \ge N$.

**Proof**: If $f(M) \ge g(M)$, it is trivial. Namely, set $N = M + 1$. So let's assume that $f(M) < g(M)$. Let $k = g(M) - f(M) \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\Delta f(n) > \Delta g(n)$ for all natural number $n \ge M$, $\Delta f(n) - \Delta g(n) \ge 1$ for all natural number $n \ge M$.

So
$$g(M) = f(M) + k \le f(M) + \sum_{i = 0}^{i = k - 1} \{\Delta f(M + i) - \Delta g(M + i)\} = f(M + k) - \sum_{i = 0}^{i = k - 1} \Delta g(M + i)$$
Then
$$f(M + k) \ge g(M) + \sum_{i = 0}^{i = k - 1} \Delta g(M + i) = g(M + k)$$
So we can set $N = M + k + 1$. $\blacksquare$

This proposition means that to prove the above proposition, it is sufficient to apply forward difference to both sides. Forward difference of $f(n) = 2^n$ is itself, but $g(n) = mn^2$ eventually becomes a constant function, but $2^l > l$ for all $l \in \mathbb{N}$, so it is done. Note that this method can be applied to arbitrary polynomials!

Comment: Hi @Ris, I truly appreciate your thorough input on this question!! I can see you are approaching from the forward difference perspective. However, given my limited knowledge in math, I find it quite challenging to comprehend your entire proof. But again, tons of thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand there is a classical induction proof for $2^n>n^2$, but this one seems to be tricky because of the constant $a$

This can be easily proven by using the case $a=1$, where you already know the result is true for all large $n$.

Let $a$ be an arbitrary, fixed number, and we are looking to prove that we can find $n$ such that $2^n > a n^2$. We will make many assumptions on $n$ to simplify the problem. This is allowed because we are only looking for one $n$.

Choose $n=2k$ even, then it is enough to find one $k$ such that
$$ 2^{2k} > 4ak^2.$$

Since $a$ is a fixed number,  for every $k>2\sqrt a$, we have $k^2> 4a$. This means that it is enough  to find $k>2\sqrt a$ such that
$$ 2^{2k} > k^4$$
take square-roots:
$$ 2^k > k^2$$
but we know by induction that this is true for all $k>4$, hence the result: any $k$ such that $k>4$ and $k> 2\sqrt a$ will do. Example: if $a=100$, then we predict that we can use any $k>20$, i.e. any $n=2k>40$. And sure enough, 
$2^{41} - 100 (41)^2 = 2199023087452 > 0$, which validates our claim.

Alternatively, here is the proof "the right way round". Let $a$ be arbitrary and fixed. we know that $2^k > k^2$ for any $k>4.$ Square both sides: we get $2^{2k}>k^4$. Now we just need to find $k>4$ such that $k^4 > a(2k)^2 = 4ak^2$. Solving this inequality gives $k>2\sqrt a$. This proves that if $k>2\sqrt a$ and $k>4$, then $n=2k$ solves
$$ 2^n > a n^2,$$
QED.

Comment: Hi @CalvinKhor, thank you so much for your input! But the $a$ here is assumed to be universal (i.e. $\forall$) rather than being existential (i.e. $\exists$). So I cannot really let $a$ be a concrete value.

Comment: @auchen_h This is still OK. For each a, I have shown that there exists an $n$. Please check again

Comment: @auchen_h also the stronger result (there exists an n such that for each a) is *wrong* so please be careful

Comment: @auchen_h I have edited the argument to make it clearer, I hope it helps

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough response! I am a bit confused on two things in your proof. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate further. First, after you set $n = 2k$, you reached $2^{2k} > 4ak^2$. Then how did you immediately reach $k>2\sqrt{a}$? I understand I can get from $2^{2k} > 4ak^2$ to $2^k>2\sqrt{a}k$ by taking square roots on both sides. Then taking $log_2$ on both sides, I can get $k > log_2{2\sqrt{a}k}$. But I can't figure out how you get from $k>2\sqrt{a}$ to $2^{2k} > 4ak^2$, or vice versa.

Comment: Second is, I understand we can make many assumptions to simplify the problem and there is even and odd in $\mathbb{N}$. However, why choosing $n = 2k$ even? Is it because it is much easier than working with odd in this problem? I guess I did get the gist of choosing $n = 2k$. Wouldn't there be any corner case got left out? I am pretty inexperienced in number theory proofs especially involving inequality. Any explanation is much appreciated!

Comment: @auchen_h I reached $k>2\sqrt a$ by writing what I want to be true, and then making it an assumption. I noticed that I can prove the $k^4$ inequality, so if I can also find $k$ such that $k^4>a n^2 = 4a k^2$, the proof can work. I chose even because I wanted to square root.